# SQL select values from an array which are not in my table

Tags: mysql

I have an array `('abc','def','ghi','jkl')`. I want to find the values which are not in mysql table.
That is, if `'def'`is not in the table, then it should show `'def'` and so on.

My query was:

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column not in ('abc','def','ghi','jkl')
```

But its wrong. How can I get the values which are not there in the column?

Comment: How are the data being stored? Can you post table structure and data sample? Please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` to get table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

```
select x.col 
from (values row('def'),row('abc'),row('ghi')) x(col)
left join table t on t.col = x.col
Where t.col is null
```

Comment: On what version of Mysql does this work?

Answer (score 0):

You should put these values first in some table  and then do "Not in" like :

**SELECT column FROM table WHERE column not in (select distinct col1 from table1).**